# Django _set.all in template with one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to output a web page with many blog posts, each of them potentially containing many images.

Models.py:

```
class FreeImage(models.Model):
    f_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="img/f")
    f_img_alt = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Views.py:

```
def home_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-id')
    freeimgs = FreeImage.objects.filter(post__in=posts)
    context = {
    'posts':posts,
    'freeimgs' :freeimgs,}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}

{% for post in posts%}
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
  {% for i in freeimgs.post_set.all %}
     <h5>Test</h5>
     <img src="{{ freeimage.f_img.url }}" alt="{{freeimage.f_img_alt}}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

`freeimgs.post_set.all` does not return anything here. I have no idea how else I could show the images corresponding to the right post inside template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reverse accessor from Post to FreeImage and not other way around

```
  {% for free_image in post.freeimage_set.all %}
     <h5>Test</h5>
     <img src="{{ free_image.f_img.url }}" alt="{{ free_image.f_img_alt}}">
  {% endfor %}
```